# Raster calculator expression which includes the "STATISTICS_MEAN" value from the raster properties

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, expression

I'm looking for raster calculator expression which includes the "STATISTICS_MEAN" value from the raster properties. How can I build the expression, that the value is automatically adapted?[image]

I want to build a workflow in the Graphical Modeler. One step should be to calculate the relativ percent of all values in the raster. For this I need to know the Statistics_mean value in advance. Calculating everything step by step is no problem, but I would like to use a workflow in the model builder. The formula I need is like this: "'raster'@1" / STATISTICS_MEANraster@1 *100

Comment: If you look closely at your screenshot you'll see in the top line the words *statistics_approximate=yes.* Is that what you want or do you want the statistics to be exact?

Comment: Could you please specify where you want to have the statistics mean value? in an output window? in a database?

Comment: @StuSmith I want to build a workflow in the Graphical Modeler. One step should be to calculate the relativ percent of all values in the raster. For this I need to know the Statistics_mean value in advance. Calculating everything step by step is no problem, but I would like to use a workflow in the model builder. The formula I need is like this: "'raster'@1" / STATISTICS_MEANraster@1 *100

Answer (score 1):

### Use "Raster Layer Statistics"

Raster Calculator is a cell-focused tool, meaining it is useful to compute values of single pixels, possibly referring also to other raster layers.
If I gat your question right, and you want to have per-band statistics of the whole layer, a tool like `Raster Later Statistics` is what you are looking for.

Menu `Processing` -> `Toolbox` -> `Raster Later Statistics`

Output will be like this:

```
QGIS version: 3.24.0-Tisler
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.9
GDAL version: 3.4.1
GEOS version: 3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0
PROJ version: Rel. 8.2.1, January 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: Release)
Algorithm started at: 2022-03-11T08:43:16
Algorithm 'Raster layer statistics' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'INPUT' : '/path/to/your/raster.jpg', 'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

Execution completed in 0.03 seconds
Results:
{'MAX': 255.0,
'MEAN': 243.5111952642747,
'MIN': 0.0,
'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE': '/tmp/processing_OfdEBl/xxx/OUTPUT_HTML_FILE.html',
'RANGE': 255.0,
'STD_DEV': 52.69975760285016,
'SUM': 2019779258.0,
'SUM_OF_SQUARES': 23035739488.420773}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Raster layer statistics' finished
HTML output has been generated by this algorithm.
Open the results dialog to check it.
```

Comment: IMHO your answer does not answer the question

Comment: Thanks Taras: I might have misunderstood the question then. If so I will delete that.